# Setting list items in ice:SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, icefaces, selectonemenu

I wish to set items from a list to the selectonemenu in icefaces.
But when I do the same I get the following error:
java.lang.ClassCastException:  cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem

The  is an entity class.

Please Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal way of creating and populating the `selectOneMenu` items would be the following:

```
private String selectedItem; // +getter +setter
private List<SelectItem> selectItems; // +getter

public Bean() {
    selectItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    for (Entity entity : getYourEntities()) {
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem(entity.getValue(), entity.getLabel()));
    }
}
```

With the following in the view (you can easily subsitite `<h:` with `<ice:`):

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectItems}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Instead of a `String` value, you can also use any `Number` (`Integer`, `Long`, etc) since JSF has builtin converters for this. But if you want to use whole objects as item value, then you need to create a `Converter`. This is described in detail in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html).